# Very slow reflow/layout in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, reflow

I have to build a table with +450 row / +90 columns dynamically and show it in Internet Explorer. I've been heavily optimizing for the last two days, and ended up creating a collection of table rows as a very long string and assigning it to the innerHTML of the tBody of the table.

it works just fine in Chrome/Mozilla, a reflow takes about .2 seconds, but it's very slow in Internet Explorer. it takes about 4 seconds to render (i say "about" because if the console is open (for time measurement) it takes 19 seconds to render). Another problem is that innerHTML is not even supported in IE9 and below. So the question is: What's the fastest way to render a whole lot of HTML as fast as possible in IE9?
HTML Sample:

```
<tr class="data-row" ><td class="hidden" style="width: -21px; padding: 
10px;">"1"</td><tdclass="structureCatagory" style="width: 119px; padding: 
10px;">"0381"</td><td class="structureCatagory" style="width: 139px; 
padding: 10px;">"Some text"</td><td class="structureCatagory" 
style="width: 139px; padding: 0px;"><img src="/Content/Images/info.png" 
onclick="Interface.OnImageClicked($(this))" ></td>...
```

And so forth for a total of 4178521 characters.
Javascript:

```
function Update() {
    var displayData = Model.GetData();
    if (displayData == undefined || displayData.length == 0)
        return false;
    var rows = "", len = displayData.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) rows += GetRow(displayData[i]);
    //until here it's very fast
    GlobalQueries.dataTableBody[0].innerHTML = rows;
    //^ this line takes alot of time
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Edit: The table itself:

```
<div class="grid">
    <table class="fixed">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<style>
    .grid { margin-top: 240px; margin-left: 10px; }
    .grid td, .header-row td { border: 1px solid black; }
    table.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try a) starting with an empty table b) assigning attributes / content to individual `<td>`s?

Comment: You could try table-layout fixed, I think usually it will wait for the entire table to load before rendering where as with fixed layout it will render as it loads, other than that I would suggest using a plugin so you can paginate it as nobody wants to see a table with 450 rows and 90 columns!

Comment: @ChrisG assigning every singe attributes at a time would probably take 43,338 times as much time, since it will have to reflow every time.
@Pete It's already layout fixed. I suppose it already renders all at once since the only contact with the DOM is in the `GlobalQueries.dataTableBody[0].innerHTML = rows`

Comment: `it takes about 4 seconds to render ... for a total of 4178521 characters` let me resentence this: `IE needs almost 4 seconds to parse and render a 4MB html-file`. And a second *little* hint: Just because you don't see an Element doesn't mean that the Browser doesn't have to render it on every single scroll; 450000+ DOM Nodes rendered on every single scroll. Maybe it's off-screen, maybe it's overlapped by sth. else, maybe repositioned ... the browser only "knows" what is visible of the node, and where on the screen,  **after rendering** the node.

Comment: I'm sorry i used the wrong words a couple times... my English isn't perfect yet. After testing in all three browsers, i understand it as such: first everything happens (page loads, js executes, 4178521 character long string gets built) quite smoothly in less than a second. Then comes the `GlobalQueries.dataTableBody[0].innerHTML = rows` part. Now it needs to be parsed: that takes 200 milliseconds in chrome/mozilla but 4 seconds in internet explorer. The "rendering" you speak about (on every scroll) comes after that and happens extremely smoothly in all three browsers. The problems are--

Comment: --that first: IE takes 8 times longer to parse the same HTML (and this parsing happens quite often as you want to filter/sort the rows), and second that innerHTML isn't supported in IE9, and there's definitely a lot of other ways i'm just looking for the fastest way. Thanks for the reply, and sorry if i misunderstood something!

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to handle scrolling yourself and only display rows that are actually visible.

Comment: So in your case, the parsing is the bottleneck, not the rendering, OK. Often it's the other way around. My first comment was not on your grammar, but trying to put some emphasis on the fact that you are talking about parsing **4 freakin MB of HTML** markup. And there's no need to do this more than once, unless your data changes, but not for sorting or filtering; here you'd just move some DOM-nodes around.

Comment: Handling scrolling myself is definitely an option, but it's really problematic and takes time to make it look good without sudden jumps and scrolls and all. @Thomas My mistake wasn't the grammar, but using the word "render" instead of "parse." Also really nice suggestion, but i can't think of a way of doing that without having to reflow everytime i remove/add an element for filtering, or switching two elements for sorting (now i have a case of parsing vs reflowing... i'll try your suggestion and be back. Thanks for the replies!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only lazy rendering will help you here. This way you will reduce the amount of HTML nodes on the page and make it lighter. You don't need to render rows that are not visible on the screen...

There are examples with jQuery, React, Polymer ... and so on.

To make the paint look faster you can batch the inserts and not insert the entire table at once but in chunks with methods like requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the answer. But just another thing: i can't use innerHTML anymore since it doesn't work with tBody in IE9 and for the lazy loading of course. the question is: What is the the fastest way to append HTML in this case? is jQuery's .append() an option? is there some native js that's faster? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Lazy loading with .empty().append() instead of .innerHTML worked, thanks!

Comment: Yes there is -> Element.insertAdjacentHTML()